# How to get value the Number value from the provided String in Java

Tags: java, string

Text:

```
"{Operator[1536335]-Sequence[1537957]-Number[60000]}"
```

Is there a efficient way to get the value of Number from the string instead of using multiple String.replaceAll?

I tried with String.replaceFirst or some string reduction technique like split with '-' .But seems little clumsy and thought there must be a better way to do this. So here I am asking the pros :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the part between square brackets after 'Number', could use a regular expression with a [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

Example:

```
    String str = "{Operator[1536335]-Sequence[1537957]-Number[60000]}";
    System.out.println(str);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*-Number\\[(.*?)\\]}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Result:

```
60000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str1 = "{Operator[1536335]-Sequence[1537957]-Number[60000]}";
    String[] oneSplit = str1.split("-");
    String[] twoSplit = oneSplit[2].split("\\u005B");
    String[] threeSplit = twoSplit[1].split("\\u005D");
    System.out.println(threeSplit[0]);
```